# some confusion in symbolic general topology

Tags: general-topology

Find the boundary and interior for each of the following subsets of $R^2$

$A= \{(x,y): y=0 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I got the answer [image]

as I'm not getting the red circle  as I have not getting. What does it  indicate, 
as I have taken it from   http://math.ucr.edu/~res/inprogress/sol20828.pdf

Comment: $N_{r}(p)$ is the neighborhood of point $p$ with radius $r$. In this case, $r=|y|$.

Comment: That must be explained somewhere in the  course, but it seems to denote the open ball centred at $(x,y)$ with radius $|y|$.

Comment: Maybe it's the open ball around (x,y) with radius |y|?

Comment: thanks to all of u@Peter@Bernard @Qurultay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **could** mean the open ball with respect to the Euclidean norm centered at $(x,y)$ with radius $|y|> 0$, more commonly denoted by $B((x,y), |y|)$.

Indeed we have $B((x,y), |y|) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 - A$ since

$$(x', y') \in B((x,y), |y|) \implies |y| - |y'|< |y'-y| \le \|(x', y') - (x,y)\|_2 < |y|$$

and therefore $|y'| > 0$ so $y' \ne 0$.

Comment: thanks a lots mechanodroid